# Series expansion of a multivariate function

Tags: series-expansion

I am new to Mathematica. I would like to understand if this output of $$\text{Series}\left[\left\{u v,\frac{u^2}{2}+w^2,\log \left(\frac{1}{u^2+1}\right)\right\},\{u,0,1\},\{v,0,1\},\{w,0,1\}\right]$$ is correct, because "by hand" I found that the jacobian matrix is $$J=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 v & u & 0 \\
 u & 0 & 2 w \\
 -\frac{2 u}{u^2+1} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and $$\text{Normal}\left[\text{Series}\left[\left\{u v,\frac{u^2}{2}+w^2,\log \left(\frac{1}{u^2+1}\right)\right\},\{u,0,1\},\{v,0,1\},\{w,0,1\}\right]\right]$$
We get as output $\{u v,0,0\}$ but it should be $\{0,0,0\}$.
Thanks.

```
\[Delta][u_, v_, w_] := {u*v, 1/2 u^2 + w^2, 
  Log[1/(u^2 + 1)]}

Normal[
 Series[{u*v, 1/2 u^2 + w^2, Log[1/(u^2 + 1)]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 
   1}, {w, 0, 1}]]

Out[124]= {u v, 0, 0}
```

Comment: Please directly post your Mathematica code instead of the LaTeX formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `Series` is not suitable for multiple vector value function. So I recommend to create the Taylor expand by hand.

```
δ[u_, v_, w_] := {u*v, 1/2 u^2 + w^2, Log[1/(u^2 + 1)]}
D[δ[u, v, w], {{u, v, w}, 1}]
D[δ[u, v, w], {{u, v, w}, 2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica must know the "smallness" of `u,v,w` !

Assuming same order try

```
Normal[Series[{u*v, 1/2 u^2 + w^2, Log[1/(u^2 + 1)]} /. {u -> eps u, v -> eps v, w -> eps w}
, {eps, 0, 2}]] /. eps -> 1
(*{u v, u^2/2 + w^2, -u^2}*)
```